# Should ANALYZE be run in a transaction?

Tags: sqlite

In sqlite (specifically version 3), should ANALYZE be run in a transaction?

If so, and I'm at the end of a long transaction that made lots of changes, is it okay to run ANALYZE in that same transaction or should that transaction be committed first and begin another transaction for the ANALYZE?

[The documentation](http://sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) doesn't say anything about this one way or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANALYZE reads the data from indexed columns and writes statistical information into some internal table.
This is somewhat similar to the following query:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO sqlite_statXXX
SELECT 'MyTable', 'MyColumn', COUNT(*), AVG(MyColumn) FROM MyTable
```

done once for every indexed column.

Like any other SQL statement that writes a small amount of data to the database, the transaction overhead will be much larger than the actual effort to write the data itself.

In your case, it is not *necessary* for your changed data to be available without the changed statistics, so you could just as well do the ANALYZE in the same transaction.

If the database is so big that ANALYZE runs for a long time, it might make sense to delay its execution until later when it does not conflict with more important transactions.